# C#: Regarding Nlog settings and usage

Tags: c#, nlog

i am curious to use nlog. i did not use it previously. so i like to use it now in my project. i have a question.

```
<rules>
    <logger name="SomeNamespace.Component.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

what does mean here SomeNamespace.Component.* ? show me the usage of this type of rule with sample code

what is `minlevel="Info"` ? what does mean **minlevel** here ?
what other option can be set for **minlevel** ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does mean here SomeNamespace.Component.* ?

It means that this rule will match any loggers which have name starting with `SomeNamespace.Component.`. Usually name of logger equals name of class where you are creating logger (but you also can provide custom logger name):

```
private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

So rule configuration above will match following logger names:

```
SomeNamespace.Component.MyClass
SomeNamespace.Component.Cool.Other.Namespace.YourClass
// etc
```

I.e. any logger created in class from `SomeNamespace.Component.` namespace will match rule. No matter how many classes with loggers you have there.

> what is minlevel="Info" ?

It's a minimal level of log messages which will be logged by logger.

```
Logger.Debug("This will not be logged");
Logger.Info("This will be logged");
```

NLog supports following log levels (you can use any of them to control which messages will be logged):

1. Trace
2. Debug
3. Info
4. Warn
5. Error
6. Fatal

Check description of each level at [NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#log-levels). Usually you should use min level `Info` which will log any error messages and some high-level details of what system is doing. For debugging purpose you can turn-on `Trace` or `Debug` level, but your log file can become huge very quickly. Performance also will hurt when you are writing lot of log messages.

Comment: are you talking about this `Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SomeNamespace.Component"); logger.Debug("...") will write to file or u mean something else?

Comment: it would be helpful if you come with small example for this `SomeNamespace.Component`

Comment: @Tridip I mean if you have namespace `namespace SomeNamespace.Component.Foo { ... }` and you have class `Bar` declared in that namespace with loger (inside Bar) then logger name will be `SomeNamespace.Component.Foo.Bar` and it will match rule pattern